# Fatal error: Index out of range (Arrays)

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3, fatal-error

I very new to Swift and programming in general, so I can't figure out where is the problem. Tried to find the answer in the existing topics - couldn't. Thanks in advance.

```
func smartAssigning(names: [String], statuses: [Bool], projects: [Int], tasks: [Int]) -> String {
    //beginig
    var collect: [Int] = [], nameLast = 0
    var candidateNumber: [Int] = []
    for x in 0...statuses.count {

        //Defines who is working
        if statuses[x] == false {
            collect.append(x)
        } else {}
    }

    // Checks for min tasks assigned among those not on vacation
    let rt: Int = tasks.min()!
    let rp: Int = projects.min()!
    for i in collect {
        if tasks[i] == rt {
            candidateNumber.append(i)
        } else {}
    }
    // if there is only 1 with min tasks - returns his number in array
    if candidateNumber.count == 1 {
        nameLast = candidateNumber[0]
    } else {
        // checks for min projects
        for e in candidateNumber {
            if projects[e] == rp {
                nameLast = e
            }
        }
    }
    return names[nameLast]
}
smartAssigning(names: ["sd", "dfsd","dfsdf"], statuses: [true, false, false], projects: [2, 1, 1], tasks: [3, 2, 1])
```

Screen:

[image: Screen]

Comment: The first error is at `for x in 0...statuses.count`– Did you try to *debug* the problem? Single-stepping the function would reveal the problem quickly.

Comment: Are the elements in the names, statuses, projects and tasks arrays all tied together? E.g. the first name is tied to the first status, the first project, and first task?

Comment: Yes, they Are. But I found my problem. Thanks to you and Martin R. Damn. so easy. Why XCODE doesn't recognize it as an error?

Comment: @JackMov Because it's a run time error.

Answer (score 1):

The error is here:

```
for x in 0...statuses.count { // Error is here

    //Defines who is working
    if statuses[x] == false {
        collect.append(x)
    } else {}
}
```

If `statuses.count` is `n`, then the maximum index is `n-1`. It should be `0..<statuses.count`. You should avoid manually creating such a range, exactly because it can cause this typo. It's much better to just do `for x in status.indices`.

On a side note, you don't need to have an `else` clause if it doesn't do anything.

Also, rather than comparing against false (`== false`), just negate the `Bool`.

```
for x in statuses.indices { // Error is here
    //Defines who is working
    if !statuses[x] {
        collect.append(x)
    }
}
```

This whole code can be written using a single `filter(_:)` expression:

```
// TODO: Give me a new meaningful name!
let collect = statues.enumerated() // Get index, status pairs
                     .filter{ index, status in !status } // filter all false statuses
                     .map{ index, status in index } // Take just the indices
```

Comment: Thx. The first error is found? Looks like it works in XCODE, but doesn't want to in CODECHALLENGE window. Says: file.swift on line 15:24: error: value of type '[Int]' has no member 'min'
        if tasks[i] == tasks.min() {
                       ^~~~~ ~~~

Comment: I have no idea what you're saying. o.0'

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kruv2n1zj0vmxvt/Screenshot%202016-12-20%2016.18.41.png?dl=0

Comment: IDK, open a new question. That seems like it should be okay

Comment: I found the reason. They use Swift 2 and it requires array.minElement() instead of array.min()